# How to use the drawables inside Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

There are lots of image (PNG) files in Android SDK. Many of them do not appear in the autocomplete list of Android Studio. A few months ago I asked a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839605/why-does-android-studio-not-recognise-some-system-drawables-in-the-android-sdk) about this, but I received no reply.

Is it that one is supposed just to copy the PNG files manually from the Android SDK and embed them to one's project?

For example, if I want to use the three dot image, is the correct way copying ic_menu_moreoverflow(DPI).png files from every `sdk/platforms/android-23/data/res/drawable-(DPI)` directory and paste them to my project? (Since there are many files for the same image, it does not seem so convenient though.)

Comment: if you have assets for your image in all densities, when you copy and paste android will place them in their respectable folders. however, consider using mipmap instead of drawables. and if you are referencing inside your XML, then you need to reference with @android:drawable/name_of_drawable

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, in XML you would use them like this:

`@android:drawable/image_name_here`

or, in code:

`android.R.drawable.image_name_here`

Comment: I did that like `@android:drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light`, but that caused a compile-time error. I am not sure but perhaps the image is in `android-23` and my minimum SDK is below that?